# Can't change longtable width for middle column

Tags: tables, longtable, columns

When I specify the width by `\begin{longtable}p{xcm}`

For example, here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}lp{2cm}lp{2cm}l}
\caption{Test}\\
\label{table:sh}\\
\hline\hline
2cm  &  2cm   & 2cm \\
\hline
Test &  test  & test  \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}lp{4cm}lp{4cm}l}
\caption{Test}\\
\label{table:sh}\\
\hline\hline
4cm  &  4cm   & 4cm \\
\hline
Test &  test  & test  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

And clearly the first and third column width have been changed but not the middle column. Why is that? How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}lp{2cm}lp{2cm}l}` means that you have 6 colums, 3 of them with specified width. Hence it is expected that the second column (`l` as left) has only width needed to enclose your `test` word.

Answer (score 2):

There are missing `&` characters to use the correct columns here -- 6 columns are defined, but only 3 `&` are used.

Either remove the inner `l` column specifiers or use additional `&` characters.

The additional `l` columns aren't necessary, in my point of view -- the table will get too wide and `LaTeX` complains about overfull boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}lp{2cm}lp{2cm}l}
\caption{Test}\\
\label{table:sh}\\
\hline\hline
2cm  & & 2cm  & & 2cm \\
\hline
Test & & test & & test  \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}lp{4cm}lp{4cm}l}
\caption{Test}\\
\label{othertable:sh}\\
\hline\hline
4cm  &  & 4cm   & & 4cm \\
\hline
Test &  & test  & & test  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong number of `&`:  you should have written

```
 x cm & & x cm & & x cm \\
```

In other words: you're not always in the column you believe you're in.